# How to list all classes contained within an SWF

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there a way to get a list of all classes contained within then currently running SWF? You could use describeType on the root and then traverse down the list to find all Classes of instances referenced within your app, but this method does not work for classes that have been included, but not referenced (local references, for example).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As i know it is not possible

Comment: To be fair, it was impossible when this answer was posted.  =)

Answer (score 14):

as of Flash Player 11.3, you can use ApplicationDomain.getQualifiedDefinitionNames().

basic example:

```
var definitions:Vector.<String> = this.loaderInfo.applicationDomain.getQualifiedDefinitionNames();
```

the following code demonstrates how to list all definitions (including classes) for a .swf file in Flash Player 11.3, with a failure message in older versions of Flash Player:

```
var t:TextField;
t = new TextField();
t.width = 1200;
t.height = 700
t.border = true;
t.background = true;
t.text = "Definition List\n";
t.appendText("========================================\n");
var definitions:*;
if (this.loaderInfo.applicationDomain.hasOwnProperty("getQualifiedDefinitionNames")) {
  definitions = this.loaderInfo.applicationDomain["getQualifiedDefinitionNames"]();
  for (var i:int = 0; i < definitions.length; i++) {
    t.appendText(definitions[i] + "\n");
    t.scrollV = t.maxScrollV;
  }
} else {
  t.appendText("Could not read classes. For a class list, open this .swf "
               + "file in Flash Player 11.3 or higher. Your current "
               + "Flash Player version is: " + Capabilities.version);
}
addChild(t);
```

For a list of classes in Flash Player 11.2 and older, you must read the bytes of the .swf and parse the class names manually. here are two well-known libraries that demonstrate:

Thibault Imbert's SWFExplorer

http://www.bytearray.org/?p=175

Denis Kolyako's getDefinitionNames()

http://etcs.ru/blog/as3/getdefinitionnames/

http://etcs.ru/pre/getDefinitionNamesSource/

Comment: Is there a way to get the namespace that they belong too? For example, if you have spark.controls.Button it would return "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark". If not the swc that a swf uses at compile time should contain the manifests of the namespaces or is there any other way a runtime to get this info?

Comment: I found that the flex-config.xml file in the SDK folder (4.6.0/frameworks/flex-config.xml) has a node called "namespaces". That has a list of namespaces and links a xml files that contain lists of classes that are in each specific namespace. I can use this to create a dictionary of a dictionary of classes in each namespace.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative maybe:

In the first frame of the embedded SWF, set a property listing all the classes you want to make available.

e.g.:

```
this.availableClasses = ["MainMenuClass", "SmileyFaceClass", "JumpButtonClass"];
```

Then, on load:

```
var classes:Array = loader.content.availableClasses;
var domain:ApplicationDomain = loader.loaderInfo.applicationDomain;
var classType:Class;
var clip:*;
for each(var className:String in classes) {
  classType = domain.getDefinition(className);
  clip = new classType();
}
```

Comment: this does not meet the poster's needs, which are stated as "get a list of all classes contained within then currently running SWF". the poster is asking for an api to introspect a .swf file, not advice on sharing a manually maintained list of strings. APIs exist for retrieving the class list (see my answer), so there is no need to manually supply an error-prone list.